# How can i change my azure Web App PHP version 7.2 to 7.1?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have the issue I want my azure web app in 7.1.

But same if I executing command which is below,

```
az webapp config set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --linux-fx-version "PHP|7.1"
```

Reference ([Configure a Linux PHP app for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-php))

Nothing will change,

If I check using below commands there is no PHP 7.1 check my screenshot,

[image]

And the Azure UI Itself also not there to change,

[image]

Please help me out from the same how can I run my web app to 7.1.

Comment: If the version you want the azure doesn't provide you could use custom image to do it. Or you could change to windows, it will be easy to change the php version.

Comment: @GeorgeChen can you hlep me how can I because I am new to azure.

Comment: You are using Linux now?

Comment: yes, I have Laravel WebApp so I just set up all from Web App Nothing did from command.

Comment: It seems PHP 7.1 does not support in Azure Web App, so you need to create the custom image yourself with setting the base image as PHP 7.1. Take a look at [How to create a custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli) and [deploy to web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker#deploy-the-image-to-azure-app-service).